# Macro for text to column then transposing the converted text to columns and inserting rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have an Excel sheet with three columns SKU, Title, and Size as shown here:

[image]

After running the macro I need the sheet to look like this:

[image]

I am stuck at adding rows to match the converted text to the column.

Comment: @BruceWayne answer is more advanced. I was trying to give you an answer that gives you some insight so you can start writing your own macros.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work?

```
Sub splitBySize()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, k As Long
Dim sizes() As String

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    sizes = Split(Cells(i, 3), ", ") 'Add sizes to an array
    If UBound(sizes) <> 0 Then ' If there's more than one size, then...
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + UBound(sizes), 1)).EntireRow.Insert
        For k = LBound(sizes) To UBound(sizes) ' This will add the sizes to the new cells inserted
            Cells(i, 3).Offset(k, 0).Value = sizes(k)
        Next k
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, it just looks at each row, puts the sizes into an array, adds rows in between, then fills in the cells with the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but change the Sheet names (i.e. `Sheet1 and Sheet2`) to the sheets in your workbook. Note that `Sheet2` is an empty sheet that desired result will be stored in it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wshI As Worksheet
Dim wshO As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim r As Integer

Sub delimited()

Set wshI = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change this to the sheet that has your data
Set wshO = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'make a new sheet and change this to its name

'This extract each size to a column (text to columns)
    wshI.Activate
 'Change "100" to the last column of your data
  wshI.Range("C2:C100").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
  :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True

i = 1
j = 3
r = 1
'This put the desired outcome into the sheet2
While wshI.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    Do While wshI.Cells(i, j) <> ""
        If j = 3 Then
            wshO.Cells(r, 1) = wshI.Cells(i, 1)
            wshO.Cells(r, 2) = wshI.Cells(i, 2)
            wshO.Cells(r, 3) = wshI.Cells(i, 3)
        Else
            wshO.Cells(r, 3) = wshI.Cells(i, j)
        End If
        j = j + 1
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    j = 3
    i = i + 1
Wend

i = 2
j = 4

'This put the data into its original format
While wshI.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    Do While wshI.Cells(i, j) <> ""
        wshI.Cells(i, 3) = wshI.Cells(i, 3) & ", " & wshI.Cells(i, j)
        wshI.Cells(i, j).Clear
        j = j + 1
    Loop
j = 4
i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data ► Get and Transform ► From Table

- Split the Size column on comma, or comma+space
- Select the SKU and title columns
- UNpivot the "other" columns
- Delete the third column; and rename the new third column "Size"
- Save the query
- Use conditional formatting to blank out the appropriate entries in columns A & B

  - The CF formula would be `=AND($A2<>$A1,$B2<>$B1)
  - The custom number format would be `;;;`